# How to get list of all java core classes?

Tags: java, swing, jakarta-ee

How it is possible to get list of all java `JDK Core` classes?? But programatically. I know i can get information from oracle site. But i would like to get in my application. To serve information to user

All solutions whitch i found resolve only how to get list of `classes` from `my package`or other `libriary  jar` file. But i would like to know how it is possible to get all `java core classes`. From example packages

`java.lang.*`
`java.util.*`

and other. I will greatful for help

Comment: have you tried the javadoc?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html. ([Classes only](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/allclasses-frame.html))

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't have an easy way to do what you want.

The typical solution is to tell your code where the java jars are stored, then open up the jars and examine them in code (Java can manipulate JARS easily).  As you extract the names of the classes (they are the same as the names of the files--thank you Java!) you can then look at each reflectively and display it if it is public.

You can even iterate over each class and print the public methods as well.

That said, last time I went searching there were a few projects that tried to support some level of Discovery.  I think one is related to Spring and there was another.  All these would do is help you get your initial list of classes though, and honestly it won't be a whole lot easier than opening the Jars and getting a file listing.